# DataGridView Row Background Color resetting

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I want to color certain rows in my dataGridview and do so succesfully with the below code, however once I add more rows to my datagridview, they all reset to white.

This code checks all the rows from a previous collection that made it in the datagridview and colors them lightblue.
These rows are matched by sets, and the background color indicates what rows are together and every set it alternates between white and blue.

Adding another set of rows to the datagridview resets the background color to white for all previous rows in the datagridview and I have no clue why, should I overload a certain event? I'm at a loss.

This is the only instance of me changing the color of anything and I have no events of any kind overwritten.

```
List<DataRow> dgvr = new List<DataRow>();

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataTaken1.SelectedRows)
{
    // Adding selected rows from the first datagridview to the set
}

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataTaken2.SelectedRows)
{
    // Adding selected rows from the second datagridview to the set
}

foreach(DataRow row in dgvr)
{
    dataTable1.Rows.Add(row); // This is the dataTable that is bound to the datagridview
    dataTable1.AcceptChanges();
    dataGridView1.Update();
}

if (bordercolor % 2 == 1)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dgvr)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataTable1.Rows.IndexOf(row)].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
    }
}

bordercolor++; // ensures that the next set has a different background color
```

**EDIT:** Here is a picture showing how i want my rows to show, alternating colors between sets, for example, grey being odd numbered sets color and light blue being even numbered sets color.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check this property instead of doing it manually:

- [DataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.alternatingrowsdefaultcellstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the help, although i need to have certain sets of varying numbers with different background colors, i'll include more code in a few, for example, have 4 rows with the same backcolor followed by 2 rows with the alternate back color between the sets. Unless i read what you linked wrong, that only works for alternating between each rows

Comment: @polixu: Well this `if (bordercolor % 2 == 1)` means you have alternating rows. If it's not what you want, please explain, and maybe add some pictures to your question.

Comment: Following your suggestions, I have added an imgur link with my great mspaint skills to show how i want my rows to show, also for the  if (bordercolor % 2 == 1), bordercolor only gets incremented once the method is called again. so every addition during this method call, which can go from 2-5 rows will have the same color. Again thanks for your time.

Comment: @polixu: Ok, thanks for the update. I edited to include the image directly in your question. If you are setting a custom style (fixed, not related to row index etc.), try iterating through cells and setting `Cell.Style`, rather than `DefaultCellStyle` on the row. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.style(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried what you suggested, it sets the color and everything, but again the moment i add another set of row to my datagridview, all the background colors go back to white as if it doesn't stick. Do you think a call to dataGridView.update() or dataGridView.invalidate() might reset the background colors? I also call dataTable.acceptchanges(), i do not know if these remove these changes.

Comment: @polixu: Comment out `acceptchanges`, it may be the problem. If it is, iterate through rows and call acceptchanges on each row instead. See if it makes any difference.

Comment: Many thanks, it works perfectly, i thought i had to call that to update the changes that i make to the dataview, removing it fixed my problem.I will also implement that you suggest about iterating through each rows.